# Esper nested event representation

Tags: esper

I want to process the following JSON message using Esper:

```
{
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Do",
    "address":[{"street":"Maplestreet","number":100,"city":"New York"}]
}
```

What is the correct way to declare the event type schema? Can someone help me construct the right: `create schema ();` statement for EPL online?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create schema Address (street string, number int, city string);
create schema Person (name string, address Address[]);
```

Comment: One more thing. How can I access the attribute properties within the array? I have tried address.street or address[0].street but getting nil response.